# Why won't javac accept `x = x+++++y`?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac

From the perspective of Compiler Theory, why would the javac compiler not accept a statement of the form `x = x+++++y` but accept `x = x+++ ++y` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `++` is a valid token for the java lexer, the statement `x+++ ++y` will be parsed into tokens as :

```
(x)(++)(+)( )(++)(y)
```

Whereas `x+++++y` will be tokenized into the invalid:

```
(x)(++)(++)(+)(y)
```

The above is invalid java because the `++` operator can only be applied to things that are numeric variables, which the result of `(x++)` is not. This type of tokenizing is a great example of the concept known as [maximal munch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch).

From the [JLS section 3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2)

> The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another lexical translation would.
>
> Thus, the input characters a--b are tokenized (§3.5) as a, --, b, which is not part of any grammatically correct program, even though the tokenization a, -, -, b could be part of a grammatically correct program.